# Is “Yelp review” a phrase that's current, or just one-off?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was drawn to the phrase, “Yelp review” appearing in the New Yorker (March 17) article, titled “New SAT Practice Questions.” It reads:

> “Write a controlled yet scathing **Yelp review** that conveys just how
>   profoundly wrong your waiter was to refer to you and your friends as
>   an “especially large” party, causing this waiter deep moral shame and
>   personal fear.”
>
> http://www.newyorker.com/humor/2014/03/17/140317sh_shouts_frazier

I surmise “yelp review” means negative review or customer’s criticism on services at the service establishments, but I’m not sure.

None of online CED, OED, and Merriam-Webster Dictionary shows “yelps review,” though they carry “peers review.”

Is “Yelp review” a coinage of the New Yorker writer?

Comment: Yelp is a web site for local business reviews.

Comment: In general, _the/a `Name` review_ means the/a review that was published in or by the publication or group `Name`. Thus, _a New Yorker/Language/Seattle Times/Yelp/Linguist List review_. Likewise, the name of the author of the review (or the book/movie/performance reviewed (or the author/director/actor of the book/movie/performance reviewed)) can appear as `Name`. _Review_ is a picture noun like _story_ or _picture,_ and they have lots of optional syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, [Yelp](http://yelp.com) is the name of a popular restaurant-review website here in the U.S. The phrase simply means "a review appearing on Yelp", in a construction analogous with "newspaper review".

Comment: I see that's why Y of yelp is capital, which I was wondering. Thank you.

Comment: They review other local businesses too, although I think it started out with restaurants, and it's still a major focus.